# How to make fragment transaction when clicked on a listitem?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have an activity where it contains an ActionBar (with four tabs) a fragment respectively assigned to each of these tabs. In these fragments I've assigned some ListAdapters filled with string values, clickable that furthermore I want to operate. When clicking on an item I want that app to send from that fragment to another. I know that I have to use FragmentManager() and FragmentTransaction() but since I'm new to Android dev I demand of any kind of help, help that is appreciated.

Here's the snippet code of one of the tabs(UserFragment.java):

```
    import android.app.ListFragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


/** This is a listfragment class */
public class UserFragment extends ListFragment 
{

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String user_items[] = new String[]
    {
        "Account",
        "Addresses",         
        "Payment Providers",
        "Profile",
        "Transactions",
        "Wallet"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, user_items);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Profile.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);            
            }       
        }); 
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}
```

The Profile.java activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Profile extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_layout);

        //Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. After a long search I learnt that if the **onCreateView()** method is static than it's all good to set listener/s but in this case while we fill an array-adapter of string than it's a no-go since first of first it has to created its View therefore doesn't let the app to make any further listeners. In order to make that available, the ***onActivityCreated(Bundle)*** should be initiated/created between **onCreateView()** and **onStart()** methods and insert the rest of the code.

Here's the solution to link a ListFragment to another FragmentActivity class:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Profile.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);            
            }       
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `OnItemClickListener` for your `ListFragment` to handle item click events. For example:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        // start your new activity here
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and my app crashes when I switch to the tab I initiated OnItemClickListener. The error was like this :"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created"

Recently inserted code is :
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
     long id) 
   {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Profile.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    
   }
         
        });