# Missing Data by adding a Fragment to a existing ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, fragment

I am trying to populate my ListView with a Footer. For that reason I created a Fragment. But I have problems passing data to the fragment. On a different place it worked just fine, the way I have done it.

```
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);     

    MenueAdapter adapter = new MenueAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.mainview_menue_item_row, data_Storage_news, 
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());    


    Intent intent_onTv = new Intent(context,
            OnTvFragment.class);

    intent_onTv.putExtra("data_Storage_tv", data_Storage_tv);

    OnTvFragment frag = new OnTvFragment();
    frag.setArguments(intent_onTv.getExtras());
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();        
    ft.commit();    

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();      
    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ontv_fragment, null);       

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    listView1.addFooterView(footer);       
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Fragment contains a ViewFlipper and works perfectly fine in another activity.

Anyone a clue what I'm doing wrong or can tell me a proper way how it's done?

Comment: Your ft `FragmentTransaction` is completely useless as you just create it and immediately commit it(without any fragments being committed in the transaction). Do you want that fragment placed in the footer layout of the `ListView`(if yes, don't do this)?

Comment: mhh ok, what better way would u recommend? :)

Comment: If you want the extra footer to scroll with the `ListView` then implement the footer as code in the `Activity`(no fragment involved). If the footer should just be below the `ListView` then it's very simple to insert a wrapper `FrameLayout` below the `ListView` and add your fragment to that `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Ok, i did it your way! I added a frame layout. But now the fragment is always visible. How can i achieve, that the fragment scrolls with the list view, and is only visible if i reach the end of the listview

Comment: **Why** do you absolutely want to use a fragment as the `ListView`'s footer? If you don't have a good answer to this question then please use my first suggestion.

Comment: Ehrm because, in my opinion fragments are used, to manage a certain part of your activity, and can easily reused at other points. In my example the  listview isnt the only part where i implemented the fragment. It is also implemented at a different activity. I just thought its the proper and easiest way to handle things in my app. Btw thx for your help :)

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to use the fragment in a `ListView`, a special widget which recycles views, a scenario for which fragments weren't designed(as they generally expect the parent view to which they are attached to be valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a Fragment as Footer to a ListView - My solution:

```
ListView.LayoutParams lp = new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        

    View footer = new View(listView1.getContext()); 

    footer = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.on_tv_fragment_empty, null);        
    footer.setLayoutParams(lp);     

    OnTvFragment frag = new OnTvFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();        
    ft.replace(R.id.ll, frag).commit();       
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    listView1.addFooterView(footer);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make sure, that `footer` is inflating an empty FrameLayout like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:background="@layout/gradient_box"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    />
```

to avoid the following bug: 
[How to make fragment transaction when clicked on a listitem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120413/how-to-make-fragment-transaction-when-clicked-on-a-listitem)

My result looks like this: 
[image]

Hope this helps anybody :)